# Migrate Easygrid from Grails 2.X to 3.X, DefaultGrailsControllerClass

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to migrate Easygrid plugin from 2.X to 3.X
I have an error that can not resolve: 
In version 2.X the Class DefaultGrailsControllerClass had a method "registerMapping", but in version 3.X of the same class this method does not exist any more.
The question is: What method I can use of the new version (3.X) class?

Please note that I can not understand very much all the Easygrid plugin code, because I am not the author.

Thanks

Comment: Could you get through this ..?   I am having hard time ...what do i replace easygrid with in grails3 ??

Comment: I couldn't get it working in grails3. I still use grails2 for my projects....I think that easygrid needs a recoding, using other way to call controller actions, like a dispatcher or something...